# How to Associate Drupal content type with CiviCRM groups?

Tags: 7, nodes, civicrm

I have created the 10 contents in Drupal. This contents are Article content type and also created the new group(group name: students) in civicrm.

Now I want to associate these content with the student group in civicrm.

could you please anyone tell me how to achieve this one ?

Answer (score 0):

With the [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module, many CiviCRM API entities are exposed as proper Drupal entities. You can then create Entity Reference fields to reference particular entities. So on your node types, create an entityreference field, target CiviCRM Groups, and you will be able to reference the groups this way